# UIImageView subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to create a custom class RoundedImageView by subclassing the `UIImageView` class.

In order to make it round, I use the following code:

```
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Where should I place this code? In the initializer? Or maybe in `layoutSubviews`? I know there's not a good idea to access properties from self within the initializer(because self may not be fully initialized), that is why I am confused and I'm not sure where to place this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical initialization for a UIView (or any class derived from UIView) looks like this

```
- (void)setup
{
    // do any initialization here
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setup];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) 
        [self setup];

    return self;
}
```

This works for views that are created by storyboard and views that are created programmatically. Source: [the CS193P videos](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550).

Answer (score 1):

The initialisation method is definitely the right place, since you want to set those properties only once.

About your concern related to acessing properties, the idea is that a property accessor could be overridden in a derived class and thus access portions of the object not already properly initialised. This is not a great concern in your case, I would say, unless you plan to override `layer`'s getter in some not fully sensible ways.